# PDF to text extraction using Poppler C API

Tags: c, linux, poppler

I need do extract the text from the PDF file.With the help of Poppler API i can able to extract all text available in that page . even i can able to get the font information like Bold and italic .But i cant able to get the size of the text.Please let me know the way to get the size of text.

Thanks

Comment: "*... get the size of the text*": You mean the font size(s?) used?

Comment: yes i need to know the size of the font

Answer (score 0):

Although late by an eternity, take a look at [`TextWord::getFontSize()`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/poppler/TextOutputDev.h#n179).